# How to send message to specific selector using ActiveMQ ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, activemq-classic

Is there any possibility to send an ActiveMQ message from a browser using amq ajax, including a topic and a specific selector?

---

I have an app in 2 parts:

PART 1 --> Web client is listening on a topic:

```
var myHandler = function(message) {console.log(message);}
amq.addListener('amqlistener', 'topic://mytopic', myHandler);
```

PART 2 --> Web app sends different orders to this topic:

```
amq.sendMessage('topic://mytopic', myData);
```

Very simple and all works OK.

---

Now, I need to filter some messages, so I have put a selector in the PART 1 like this:

```
amq.addListener('amqlistener', 'topic://mytopic', myHandler, {selector:"dev='xxxxx'"} );
```

and here is (in PART 2) where I don't get the way to send a message including this specific selector.

Any help is well welcome :)

Comment: Selectors only apply to listeners. If you want to segregate messages from the producer side, use a different topic.

Comment: Thanks. But, if I use different topics whenever I need different selector, I would have more than thousand topics, and this is not my intention. I need one topic with different selectos...

Answer (score 0):

You don't send with selectors, you send with headers/properties that the selector can use to filter out messages.

amq has a function that looks like this:

```
var sendJmsMessage = function(destination, message, type, headers)
```

It accepts headers. I would supply your header 'dev' with value 'xxxxx' there.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried this, but amq.js only uses this function to create  the listeners, sending to the server side 'listen' in type. I don't know why is not yet implemented that function for sending messages from javascript side.

Comment: Looking at the code, yes, your are right. I did not actually test the code, just realized the function looks right for the job. Adding a custom servlet for that would be very simple though. But I get your point. Will remove this answer.

Comment: I have used stomp and mqtt over websocket with ActiveMQ with good results. They have more options and if you can cope with websocket as a requirement, you will like it.